# How to find adjoint operator?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, adjoint-operators

Let $(X,\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle)$ be a Hilbert Space over $K$ with orthonormal basis $(x_n)$, and let $(\lambda_n)\in K$ be a bounded sequence. The mapping $T:X\to X$ is defined by

$Tx:=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\lambda_n\langle x,x_n\rangle x_n$, $x\in X$.

Find the adjoint operator $T^*$ of $T$.

Comment: Remember the defining characteristic of the adjoint operator. Write it out. Look at it.

Comment: along with the comment of @DanielFischer, you may try for the finite dimensional case first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clearly the adjoint of $T$ is defined as
$$
T^*x:=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\overline{\lambda}_n\langle x,x_n\rangle x_n.
$$
To see that, note that $\langle Tx,x_n\rangle=\lambda_n\langle Tx,x_n\rangle$ and
$$
\langle x,y\rangle=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \langle x,x_n\rangle\overline{\langle y,x_n\rangle},
$$
and hence
$$
\langle Tx,y\rangle=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \langle Tx,x_n\rangle\overline{\langle y,x_n\rangle}
=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \lambda_n\langle x,x_n\rangle\overline{\langle y,x_n\rangle},
$$
while
$$
\langle x,T^*y\rangle=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \langle x,x_n\rangle\overline{\langle T^*y,x_n\rangle}
=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \langle x,x_n\rangle\overline{\bar\lambda_n\langle y,x_n\rangle},
=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \lambda_n\langle x,x_n\rangle\overline{\langle y,x_n\rangle}.
$$